# Merging of pandas dataframe with calculations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a couple of pandas dataframes.

DF A:

| id | date | avg | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 27/06/2021 | 10 | 5 |
| 1 | 28/06/2021 | 12 | 4 |

DF B:

| id | date | avg | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 27/06/2021 | 8 | 5 |
| 1 | 28/06/2021 | 6 | 6 |
| 1 | 29/06/2021 | 11 | 10 |
| 2 | 27/06/2021 | 3 | 10 |
| 2 | 28/06/2021 | 3 | 10 |

Basically, these are simplifications of intermediate tables aggregated from various Big Data sources. How can I merge these data frames so that the average for a id+date is correct (i.e. it is (avg1 * count1 + avg2 * count2)/(count1 + count2))

The expected DF for the above two should be like this:

| id | date | avg | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 27/06/2021 | 9 | 10 |
| 1 | 28/06/2021 | 8.4 | 10 |
| 1 | 29/06/2021 | 11 | 10 |
| 2 | 27/06/2021 | 3 | 10 |
| 2 | 28/06/2021 | 3 | 10 |

Thanks.

Comment: Merge on id and date, then do your calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way:

```
out=df1.merge(df2,on=['id','date'],suffixes=('_1','_2'),how='left'))
```

Now do calculations:

```
out['avg']=out.eval("(avg_1*count_1+avg_2*count_2)/(count_1+count_2)")
out['count']=out.eval("count_1+count_2")
out=out.drop(out.filter(like='_').columns,1)
```

Finally:

```
df2.update(out)
```

Comment: Does the df2.update(out) update the second dataframe with values from out? Does this mean that the final merged df is df2?

Comment: @sridharraman yes `df2.update(out)` update the second dataframe with values from `out`

Comment: @sridharraman btw If any of the solution solved your problem then you can try considering accepting answer..Thanks ***:)***

Answer (score 3):

You may can do

```
s = pd.concat([df1,df2])
cnt = s.groupby(['id','date'])['count'].sum()
amount =  (s['avg']*s['count']).groupby([s['id'],s['date']]).sum()/cnt
amount.name='avg'
out = pd.concat([cnt,amount],axis=1).reset_index()
out
Out[34]: 
   id        date  count   avg
0   1  27/06/2021     10   9.0
1   1  28/06/2021     10   8.4
2   1  29/06/2021     10  11.0
3   2  27/06/2021     10   3.0
4   2  28/06/2021     10   3.0
```